# Making a vertically equal partition on a Centralized Webpage, without using Frames and Table concept ?

Tags: html, web

I'm trying to make a vertical split in a centralized webpage. I'm doing the split with the concepts of frames and tables but its not satisfying my expectation.

I tried using div for separation but found it difficult to mange and running into conflict. I google for solution but not find anything related. I'll be sorry if it is very basic. Any help and suggestions would greatly appreciated.

Thanking in Advance, Regards...

Comment: you can add divs with percentage as width and have them float next to each other. i.e. `<div style="width:50%;float:left;">1</div><div style="width:50%;float:left;">2</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0;
        }
        #left {
            width:50%;
            height: 600px;
            float: left;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #right {
            width:50%;
            height: 600px;
            float: right;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: note i put height to 600 just to see the div, change it to fit your need

Comment: Thank you Alloush, Sorry for delay in reply. I tried with this idea, the thing is there will lot of div will be there for the contents on both sides and there will animations and slides for the contents on both sides.

Comment: Thank you Alloush, Sorry for delay in reply. Main thing is my header is fixed and my web page is scrolling web page.                                          I tried with this idea, the thing is there will lot of div will be there for the contents on both sides and there will animations and slides for the contents on both sides. Sorry if I'm wrong, please put me in the right direction. any suggestion will help.

Comment: You are welcome @Raj , and with my pleasure to help you. If you want as fixed div at top of Html page, then create a div and give it fixed position(as example facebook) in addition do margin for the left and right div with value equal to the fixed div, then add in css for left and right div overflow : auto
then every thing will be ok.

any help i will be so happy to help you sir